# is there a way to clean out the intentet/network?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have Ubuntu 20+.  I recently changed VPN. I found  ProtonVPN, which was highly recommended by PC magazine. It was faster and had a GUI interface for Ubuntu and also I could use Thunderbird for email.  But after 3 days I started having problems, Thunderbird wouldn't connect and when that happened I couldn't login to webmail until I disconnected VPN.  Anyway, now that computer will not even connect to the internet whether or not I am running protonVPN.  I figure it must have done something to whatever network settings or somthing that messed it up so that it will not connect.   Any ideas how to clean that all out?
Thanks
PS sorry if I didn't explain it well but I don't know the proper terms for what I want to do.

Comment: Please be specific with details; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the end of the *development* cycle that started after release of 18.04 (LTS cycles are two years long starting after the last LTS; so do you mean you don't want to it work with 20.04 but the 20.10-22.04 cycle release? or something else?  (20.10 was six months into the development of 22.04 & a subsequent cycle to 20.04 which was the conclusion of the prior cycle). Or alternatively are you asking about Ubuntu Core 20 & Ubuntu Core 22 (ie. *snap* only products thus the *year* format of your release)?  it's unclear.

Comment: There have been many questions on this site about protonvpn breaking networking. Try searching the site for protonvpn.

Comment: They list Ubuntu 20+ on their site to select which version of protonVPN to download.   Is there some command I can enter to tell exactly wihch version I have?   Otherwise I think it's maybe 22

Comment: I did do a search for protonvpn and found things that worked.   Thanks for the suggestion.